# AngularJS numeric text input: Directive vs. Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My project has a form with around 16 text fields.  The input needs to be numeric, and different fields will have different min/max values.  I was able to find the following jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/thomporter/DwKZh/) and adapt the parsing to the following (http://jsfiddle.net/WdBju/):

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('numbersOnly', function(){  
   return {  
     require: 'ngModel',  
     link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {  
       modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {  

           if (inputValue == undefined) {  
               return '';  
           }  

           var firstParse = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9 . -]/g, '');  

           var safeParse = firstParse.charAt(0);  
           var prepParse = firstParse.substring(1,firstParse.length);   

           var secondParse = safeParse + prepParse.replace(/[^0-9 .]/g, '');  

           var n = secondParse.indexOf(".");  
           var transformedInput;  

           if (n == -1) {  
               transformedInput = secondParse;  
           }  
           else {  
               safeParse = secondParse.substring(0,n+1);  
               firstParse = (secondParse.substring(n+1,secondParse.length)).replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');  
               n = 2;  

               if (firstParse.length <= n) {  
                   transformedInput = safeParse + firstParse;  
               }  
               else {  
                   transformedInput = safeParse + firstParse.substring(0,n);  
               }  
           }  

           var min = -25;  
           var max = 25;  

           if (transformedInput!=inputValue ||   
               transformedInput < min ||   
               transformedInput > max) {  

               var returnValue;  

               if (transformedInput < min || transformedInput > max) {  
                   returnValue = transformedInput.substring(0,transformedInput.length-1);  
               }  
               else {  
                   returnValue=transformedInput;  
               }  

               modelCtrl.$setViewValue(returnValue);  
               modelCtrl.$render();  
           }           

           return returnValue;           
       });  
     }  
   };  
});
```

I am happy with the parsing, but the min/max and precision values are hard-coded in.  Should I leave this as a directive and pass variables?  Or would a function be more appropriate?

Comment: Which browsers do you need to support?

Comment: In current browsers you can specify `input type=number`. No directive needed.

Comment: We're going to support Chrome, Firefox, and Internet Explorer 8+.  I tried to use 'input type = number', but the text field still allowed me to enter text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd keep it as is and add custom attributes to pass in the min and max values:

```
<div ng-controller="Numeric">
    <br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="number" required="required" class="numbers-only" minvalue="-27" maxvalue="45" />
</div>
```

And in your directive (of course you should have some sanity checks and sensible defaults):

```
var min = parseInt(attrs.minvalue);
var max = parseInt(attrs.maxvalue);
```

I've forked your fiddle and made the changes here: http://jsfiddle.net/XaqSs/

Answer (score 1):

One potential option is to sidestep a custom directive completely and use the input type=number attribute.

```
<input type="number" min="5" max="18" step="0.5" value="9" name="shoe-size">
```

More on it here: http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/

It's not supported by all browsers though, and firefox especially is lagging in support: http://caniuse.com/#search=number